# Working with Paypal IPN

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

What I want to do is have a buy it now button somewhere on my site. When users log on they can click it and pay X amount, then after the transaction has completed I need a script to update  1 field in the database with a value.

Someone recommended using paypal ipn for this.

Is that the best solution for what I am trying to achieve?

Will I need some additional script to work with it or is it "ready-made" with just specific database variables requiring changes?

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has a much nicer workflow for this that does not make the user wait an undetermined time for his payment to arrive: [Paypal Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/). With this you actually do know that he paid with paypal the very minute he comes back from the paypal page, and you can do all the things needed to make the transaction happen on your side as well.